# Unable to parse the date in the url Django

Tags: python, django

I have a url like this get method in a browser it says 404 page not found error

```
http://localhost:8000/getup/downloadrange/ef46219d-7b33-4bdc-aab1-c3bf073dca0e/datebottom=2019-10-10&datetop=2020-10-01/
```

My urls.py is like this

```
path(
    "downloadrange/<uuid:id>/(?P<datebottom>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})&(?P<datetop>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$",
    views.getup,
    name="getup",
),
```

The url pattern is not found for this. Kindly help me in this regard

my views.py

```
def getup(request, id, dateone, datetwo):
    queryset_two = (
        getup.objects.filter(process_id=id)
        .filter(created_on__date__range=[dateone, datetwo])
        
    )
    return render_to_csv_response(qs)
```

Comment: add your `views.py` too

Comment: Passing paramters like this is more usually done with a GET than a POST, so you'd specify `/?datebottom=2019-1010&datetop=2020-10-01

Comment: I tried with out prams it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid `url` you are expecting according to your `configuration` is:

```
http://localhost:8000/getup/downloadrange/ef46219d-7b33-4bdc-aab1-c3bf073dca0e/2019-10-10&2020-10-01/
```

**NOT**

```
http://localhost:8000/getup/downloadrange/ef46219d-7b33-4bdc-aab1-c3bf073dca0e/datebottom=2019-10-10&datetop=2020-10-01/
```

Your views have that capacity to take `datebottom` and `datetop` automatically from your `url` if it is valid.

#### Edit

As you are using `path`, the url confs is different. So, we will change from *path* to [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#re-path) to support *regex*:

```
from django.urls import re_path
re_path(
    "downloadrange/(?P<id>[0-9a-f-]+)/(?P<datebottom>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})&(?P<datetop>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$",
    views.getup,
    name="getup",
),
```

Comment: It is not taking the url if I remove the date top and date bottom

Comment: What do you mean by `not taking`?

Comment: It is throwing page not found error. I have removed the datebottom, datetop parameters

Comment: Can you copy the new url and paste it here.

Comment: Here is the url  http://localhost:8000/getup/downloadrange/ef46219d-7b33-4bdc-aab1-c3bf073dca0e/2019-10-10&2020-10-01/